Derivation of sifting property of Dirac Delta Distribution from Dirac sequence, one property isn't used
I want to start from the properties of the dirac sequence to derive its defining characteristic.
To show: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x) dx =f(0)$
Dirac sequence $\delta(x)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$:
$
1. \delta_n(x) \geq 0\\
2. \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x) dx = 1\\
3. \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R} \backslash ]-\epsilon,\epsilon[} \delta_n(x) dx = 0 \text{ for all $\epsilon > 0 $}
$
There are different yet equivalent defininitions I believe.
I want to think of the singular distribution $\delta$ as the limit of the dirac sequence.
Now my attempt of proofing this property:
$
|f(0) - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta_n(x) f(x) dx| = |f(0) - \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \delta_n(x) f(x) dx| = |f(0) - f(\bar{x})\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \delta_n(x) dx| \\ = |f(0) - f(\bar{x})| \rightarrow 0
$
With $-\epsilon \leq \bar{x} \leq \epsilon$ and using property 3, the mean value theorem and property 2 from left to right.
Is this proof correct?
Where should I need property 1?
What do we need to know about $f$, please assume it is continous?
Thanks for your comments and help!

You should share precisely how you got the second equality using the mean value theorem, as it does not seem to be correct to me. Also, the reason for $\delta_n \geq 0$ in this definition is likely so that $|\delta_n|_{L^1} = 1$ for all $n$, which allows us to use the dominated convergence theorem.

Isn't this just the mean value theorem for the definite integral? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem?wprov=sfla1 ; what do I get by dominated convergence theorem, the integrability? But don't I need a dominating function and 0 isn't dominating?

It is sufficient that $f$ is continuous. You will note that is all the mean value theorem requires of it. We can take the $\delta_n$ to be $C^\infty$ if needed. Rather than subtracting the integral from $f(0)$ and taking the absolute value, you can just do the same manipulation to the integral alone to show it is equal to $f(\bar x)$ and since $-\epsilon < \bar x<\epsilon$, as $\epsilon \to 0$, so does $\bar x$, and thus by continuity, $f(\bar x) \to f(0)$ by continuity. This is the exact way you got your conclusion of the limit $\to 0$, but dropping the excess baggage you dragged along.

So my assumption of continuity was enough? Good, that's what I hoped for. When first trying to proof this, I used a inequality, therefore the absolute value. But you rightly noted, it's not necessary. Thanks for the confirmation.

And continuity in an environment of zero is enough, isn't it?
